# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Desktop Browser environment does not work in Facebook

Tags: facebook, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I have created a simple application using Worklight v6.0 and dojo (1.9 version) and I want to put this app on facebook. I've followed these steps:

1. Created a Worklight project and application
2. Configured the dojo library
3. Added the Desktop Browser environment
4. Configured my app on facebook based on this [Information Center article](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devenv/t_manually_migrating_Facebook_apps.html)

I've put this URL as the Canvas URL parameter: 
`http://host:port/apps/services/www/application_name/desktopbrowser/` but the app doesn't load  and Facebook is returning `The server refused the connection`.

the desktopbrowser environment is running on my localhost browser and an external machine can access to my app.

Is there anything that I must do in Worklight v6.0 or in Facebook to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Canvas URL is missing the Worklight Server's context root, for example:

```
http://myHost:10080/fbtest/apps/services/www/fbapp/desktopbrowser/
```

Where `fbtest` is your context root, which is your project name by default.

In my tests the app was successfully loaded and displayed:

Make sure to also setup the `publicWorkLightHostname` in server\conf\worklight.properties.
See if that helps.

See full-size image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2xEI.png
[image]

Comment: ty for for the quick replay, I added the parameter (projectName) and i can access to the link from my browser (before this change i cant) but facebook stills returning "The server refused the connection".

Comment: 1) is the server in a private network or public internet? 2) is this other computer in the same network? 3) are you trying to connect to your external IP address?

Comment: Yes "3)" I am trying to connect with my public address (im setting on facebook my public IP not my private). And people from external network can access to my worklight app thought my external ip.

Comment: See my updated answer. This works for me. My only guess is that something with the access to the machine is not right; the environment itself works correctly.